# PHP| PEAR:MDB2 vs PDO vs Native-PHP (Raw)

Tags: php, database, pdo, pear, dao

After doing a sort of a research through out the Internet(And here at Stackoverflow) - I'm still struggling to decide which method is best for me to learn/use and dig more when programming in PHP.

I understand some of the advantaged of using **DAO when dealing with DB over using straight mysql_*** functions spread out across the application files.

When it comes to decide between **MDB2 vs PDO** - one thing that shine in favor of PDO is the fact that it doesn't abstract the mysql_* functions it talks directly to the mysql api just as the mysql_* do. It is also a compiled C extension to PHP so is very fast. While MDB2(or other libraries) are written in PHP so they need to be parsed at runtime and sit on top of the mysql_* functions. So, In terms of speed PDO wins?!?

When it comes to compare **DB abstraction layer over native-non-abstracted-PHP** way shines the 
security advantages of DB abstraction layers in the way of using binder params(prepared statements) that will prevent most sql injection attacks, plus it is easier to switch RDBMS type in the future if there is a need/request for that - even though it is not that common - (there are other advantages and nice consuming time feature in those DAO libraries).

Anyway I hope that there are experts who can assist me to decide rather I should use one of those libraries and if so, which one is the most recommended?, or should I write my own DAO library that will serve me through all my projects and will get improved with years?.

Thanks.

Comment: PDO may have a compiled component, but it still does a lot of processing that the 'raw' interfaces don't. There's still overhead, but in different places. The only good answer you'll get from here is to try pdo v.s. mdb2 v.s. "raw" and see which one is better in your particular case.

Comment: I did practiced PEAR:MDB2 - The dilemma is between using one of those Libraries(MDB2,PDO,ADOdb..) and if so than which one is the most recommended(since they are all basically for the same purpose with a little syntax different), or should I abstract my own DAO - this way I will know exactly how the code is look like and I could take full control over it instead of leaning on 3rd dimension code?!? Plus from what I understand PDO out-perform other libraries cause he communicates directly with the database instead of through some abstraction built on top of mysql_* functions

Comment: mysql_*() isn't abstraction. They're direct calls to the underlying libmysql client libraries, just as PDO's are. mysql_*() just maps more directly onto the library calls.

Comment: Yes I do realize that mysql_*() isn't abstraction, what I referred to is - should I built my own DAO library, which is in fact abstracting layer for the database using the raw methods isn't it? 
If one creates a DB class that will handle all his app DB connections and query/fetching data - isn't it abstracting DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ask yourself the questions:

- Is my code the bottleneck, or is it the database? When you're doing thousands of simple queries against the database, slow php code is a problem. When you're doing only a couple of dozen queries per request, the overhead of the db layer will probably not be noticable
- Will you ever need to switch to a different db system? If you're doing the work for a client with clear requirements, you're most likely locked to a DMBS anyway, and you don't have to care about interoperability.

Also, MDB2 is pretty aged now. If I were you, I'd use Doctrines DBAL - it can be used without Doctrine itself, and it sits on top of PDO. I would not use the old "native" mysql_* functions.

Comment: So basically you prefer using an abstraction layer for most cases except those in which there are more than a couple of dozen queries against the DB?, you recommend to avoid the "native: mysql_*() function at any cost, even when abstracting own DB class abstraction layer library? 

Never heard before about Doctrines DBAL - if sits on top of PDO - why just using PDO, because of the lack of feature?
Good to know MDB2 is old, first time I hear about it.

Thanks!